# DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR jboss 5.1.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

```
2017-02-08 16:58:54,022 INFO  [org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment] (main) deploy, ctxPath=/IAPFxStruts
2017-02-08 16:58:54,060 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/IAPFxStruts]] (main) Error configuring application listener of class com.dikshatech.iap.session.IapSessionListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/dikshatech/common/utils/LoggerUtil
    at com.dikshatech.iap.session.IapSessionListener.<clinit>(IapSessionListener.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:264)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3859)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4393)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: please help me to solve this.  also new to java .I'm using jboss 5.1.0...Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 1):

You need to add com/dikshatech/common/utils/LoggerUtil in your classpath. If it is from jar file, then jar file should be present in web-inf/lib folder of your war/ear file. Or else you can add this jar in lib folder of your JBOSS.